# How to make Primary Key in Sql Server Using Alter Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have forgot create a primary key for my table. Now I want to update the `DocDay_Id` column and make it the primary key. How can I do it?

My code is below.

I tried this syntax but it is not correct.

```
ALTER TABLE DoctorDays 
ALTER COLUMN DocDay_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL

Create table DoctorDays    
(    
    DocDay_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,    
    Doc_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Doctor(Doc_Id) NOT NULL,    
    Day_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Dayss(Day_Id) NOT NULL    
)
```

Comment: please see documentation first !

Comment: What you **cannot** do is add an `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column later on - that's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a clustered primary key on an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE DoctorDays ADD CONSTRAINT PK_DocDays
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DocDay_Id);
```

To create a non clustered primary key on an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE DoctorDays ADD CONSTRAINT PK_DocDays
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (DocDay_Id);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df94f)**

See the document in below link:

**[Alter Statement Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)**